# Let $N$ be a coatomic module of $M$. Then $N$ is coneat in $M$ if and only if $N$ is coclosed in $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

First and foremost, some definitions. Every modules will be assumed right $R$ modules. We say that  a submodule $N$ of $M$ **is coneat in** $M$ if for each simple module $S$, every module morphism $N \to S$ can be extended to a morphism $M \to S$.  We say that a submodule $N$ of $M$ **is coclosed in** $M$ if  $N/K \ll M/K$  implies that $K=N$ for each submodule $K$ of $N$. Recall that $\ll$ means [superfluous submodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension).

Last but not least, $M$ is called **coatomic** if every proper submodule $N$ of $M$ is contained in a maximal submodule of $M$. What I'm aiming to prove is the following claim:

Let $M$ be a module and $N$ be a coatomic module of $M$. Then $N$ is coneat in $M$ if and only if $N$ is coclosed in $M$.

For the first implication let's suppose that $N$ is coneat in $M$, so I want to prove that $N$ is coclosed by contradiction. So let's suppose that $N$ is coneat but it is not coclosed, this is, $N/X \ll M/X$ for some proper submodule $X \leq N$ ($X \neq N$). Since $N$ is coatomic, then $X$ is contained in a maximal submodule, let's say $K$ of $N$. But I don't know how to make further progress with the proof. For the other implication I'm run out of ideas. I  mean I need to suppose there is a morphism $N \to S$ where $S$ simple but I need to extend this morphism to another $M \to S$. Somehow I know that if $S$ is simple then its the quotient of a maximal module but I don't know how to apply our hypothesis.

Comment: What is X in the first paragraph?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Hi Martin, I just corrected that paragraph. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first implication, we can continue as follows. We are assuming that $N$ is coneat, that $N/X$ is superfluous in $M/X$, and that $X$ is contained in a maximal submodule $K$ of $N$. Now $S=N/K$ is simple, and by assumption the canonical map $N\to S$ lifts to a map $M\to S$, say with kernel $U$. Then $U$ is a maximal submodule of $M$, and $U\cap N=K$. Thus $U+N=M$, so $U/X+N/X=M/X$, which by assumption implies that $U/X=M/X$, and hence that $U=M$, a contradiction. Thus $N$ is coclosed in $M$.

For the other implication, suppose that $N$ is coclosed but not coneat, so there exists a simple module $S$ and a map $N\to S$, say with kernel $K$, which does not extend to $M$. Now $N/K$ is not superfluous in $M/K$, so there exists a proper submodule $U$ of $M$ containing $K$ such that $U+N=M$. Then $U\cap N$ is not equal to $N$, so equals $K$, and hence $M/U\cong N/N\cap U=N/K=S$ is simple, so $U$ is maximal, and the map $M\to M/U=S$ extends $N\to N/K=S$, a contradiction. Thus $N$ is coclosed.

Comment: I guess both arguments can be rewritten slightly to avoid the use of proof by contradiction.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for the late response but I've been trying to understand the detail from your second implication and it's not clear to me. I mean why $N/K$ is not superfluous in $M/K$, I'm very lost understanding why if $U  \cap N$ is not equal to $N$ and why this implies is equal to $N$. Also the first isomorphism between $M/U \cong N \ N \cap U$ is confusing me. @andrewhubery

Comment: $K$ is a proper submodule of $N$. If $N/K$ is superfluous in $M/K$, then $N$ being coclosed implies $K=N$, a contradiction. So $N/K$ is not superfluous in $M/K$.

Comment: We have $U+N=M$, so if $N\subseteq U$, then $U=M$, but $U$ is proper. So $U\cap N$ is strictly smaller than $N$.

Comment: We have $M=U+N$, and the second isomorphism theorem gives $(U+N)/U\cong N/U\cap N)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Things are more clearer now. But the reason why $U \cup N =K$ is because the image of ever  submodule over the morphism $\phi: N \to S$ is gonna be $S$ or $0$ and in this case. In this case since $U \cup N $ is properly contained in $N$ it follows by the fact that S is simple that $\phi( U \cup N )=0$ so $U \cup N =K$ where $K =Ker(\phi)$?

Comment: $U$ contains $K$ by construction, and doesn’t equal $N$. Since $K$ is maximal, we must have $U\cap N=K$.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Your whole answer is now completely clear! I just selected it as favorite response. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry @andrewhubery I thought I competely understood the proof. But still not clear why in your first implication $U$ is maximal in $M$?

Comment: We showed that $M/U\cong S$ is simple, so $U$ is maximal in $M$.